# Hide a row after an IMPORTRANGE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 files, and i'm importing 3 columns form the first file to the second, what i want to do is to hide a row if the value in the 3rd column imported is true.
I found that script online very useful:

```
//GLOBALS
// Sheet the data is on.
var SHEET = "D&D Miniatures";
// The value that will cause the row to hide. 
var VALUE = "TRUE";
// The column we will be using 
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 3
 
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  //Ensure on correct sheet.
  if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    
    //Ensure we are looking at the correct column.
    if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){
      //If the cell matched the value we require,hide the row. 
      if(cellValue == VALUE){
        activeSheet.hideRow(cell);
      };
    };
  };
}
```

The problem is that it works just when you manually modify a cell, is it possible to adapt taht code to an IMPORTRANGE?

Comment: Please provide an example of the sheet and the data you have and the result you want.

Comment: Couldn't you simply not import the row(s) with True in column  3?

Answer (score 0):

This code will add a new menu when you open the file called "Hide Rows". Just select menu item "Hide Rows with Column 3 = True" after your import and it will go through each row and hide any row where column 3 = true is considered 'truthy.'  Column 3 will be considered true if it is "TRUE" or "True" or "true" or "1"

**ADDED onEdit()**

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Hide Rows')
  .addItem('Hide Rows with Column 3 = True','hide')
  .addItem('Unhide all rows','unhide')
  .addToUi();
};

function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if(sheet.getName() != "D&D Miniatures"){
      return;
    }else{
      hide();
    };
};

function hide(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('D&D Miniatures');
  const data = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getMaxColumns()).getValues();
  
  data.forEach((datum,index) => {
    datum[2]==true ? sheet.hideRows(index+1,1) : false;
  });
}

function unhide() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('D&D Miniatures');
  sheet.unhideRow(sheet.getRange("A:A"));
}
```

Comment: That code is very useful, but my terget is to build something clickless, when the data is imported, it automatically hide the row if the 3rd column is true

Comment: I've added an onEdit() function.